# Check if the sql command gets timeout through powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, powershell, scripting

I wrote a script whose purpose is to take all the files under a particular folder and in a loop to perform on the files SQL procedures in parallel (3 files at the same time).
I've seen some timeouts in the database but Powershell does not give me an error message about that. Is there a way to get errors about these timeouts?

I tried to deal with the problem by increasing the timeout value and yet the problem is not solved so I'll have to at least have a test on the subject or an error message.

I added the increased timeout to the script in the connection string and with: $Command.CommandTimeout =

```html
param($fileName)
 
Import-Module sqlps -DisableNameChecking

$sqlserver = "SQLSERVERNAME"
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = "server=SQLSERVERNAME;integrated security = True;connection Timeout=60;"
 
$Connection.Open()
$Command = $Connection.CreateCommand()
$Command.CommandTimeout = 60
 
#Start procedure
 
$Command.CommandText = "EXEC [DBNAME].[dbo].[usp_procname] @FileName"
$Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", $fileName)
$Command.Connection = $Connection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $Command
$DataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataTable)

$Connection.Close()
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you executing the procs using `SqlCommand`? You can catch a SqlException in Powershell and handle timeouts as needed.

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: How are you invoking your 3 parallel instances?

Comment: I use the invoke-parallel command.